# How to solve $x^4+8x-1=0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, radicals, quartics

Any idea how to solve the following equation?

$$x^4+8x-1=0$$

I tried to find some obvious roots of this equation so it could help me to find the other roots (if it has more then $1$) but I had no success, and I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: You tagged this as differential equations and only differential equations but gave no context. Can you at least include what methods you tried?

Comment: This polynomial is irreducible (over $\Bbb Q$).  Were you looking for exact forms of the solutions (i.e. with nested square roots and such), or are you just looking for a numerical approximation?

Comment: Was the question to find the roots or the number of solutions ?

Comment: Exact solutions can be found but are rather nasty; This might help you: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%2B8x-1%3D0+

Comment: Based on wolframs answer, you are going to have a VERY tough time trying to factor it.

Comment: i have found this thing here $$-2.040041812501595580690236468561576619596897396475252490779558537824042326907495981877365969361518103,$$

Comment: I think without using wolfram u can just predict the number of solutions the equation will have and where they may lie

Comment: @Omnomnomnom ,the question is to find the roots.

Comment: @KristianMihalaj is this a question from a textbook?  Then perhaps there is a typo in the original text.

Comment: This is an exercise from a Math olympiad in my country.The question was : Find the roots of the following equation.

Comment: Either you've miscopied the equation, or this was a very poor Olympiad question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be a real root a little above zero, as your polynomial has $f(0)=-1, f(1)=8$  You can use any root finding technique from here.  Bisection is easy-try $f(\frac 12)$ and replace the endpoint of the interval $(0,1)$ that has the same sign as $f(\frac 12)$.  This isn't the fastest, but it will work.  There are other techniques in any numerical analysis text.  The [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) will have an easy time here.  There is another root near $x=-2$.  Graphing the function will show that, then you can use the same technique.  The other two roots are complex.

Here is the bisection $$\begin {array} {c c c c c c}a&b&(a+b)/2&f(a)&f(b)&f((a+b)/2)\\0&1&0.5&-1&8&3.0625\\0&0.5&0.25&-1&3.0625&1.003906\\0&0.25&0.125&-1&1.003906&0.000244\\0&0.125&0.0625&-1&0.000244&-0.49998\\0.0625&0.125&0.09375&-0.49998&0.000244&-0.24992\\0.09375&0.125&0.109375&-0.24992&0.000244&-0.12486\\0.109375&0.125&0.117188&-0.12486&0.000244&-0.06231\\0.117188&0.125&0.121094&-0.06231&0.000244&-0.03103\\0.121094&0.125&0.123047&-0.03103&0.000244&-0.0154\\0.123047&0.125&0.124023&-0.0154&0.000244&-0.00758\\0.124023&0.125&0.124512&-0.00758&0.000244&-0.00367\\0.124512&0.125&0.124756&-0.00367&0.000244&-0.00171\\0.124756&0.125&0.124878&-0.00171&0.000244&-0.00073\\0.124878&0.125&0.124939&-0.00073&0.000244&-0.00024 \end {array}$$

The root is always between $a$ and $b$.  The length of the interval gets cut in half each step.  You can see the root is just below $x=1/8$, which you might guess as $x^4$ is rather small, so you want $8x-1$ to be a tiny amount positive.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite our equation in the following form
$(x^2+k)^2-(2kx^2-8x+k^2+1)=0$.

We want that $2kx^2-8x+k^2+1=2k(x+a)^2$ for which we need $16-2k(k^2+1)=0$,
which gives $k^3+k-8=0$.

The last equation has unique positive root.

Thus, we get $(x^2+k)^2-2k\left(x-\frac{2}{k}\right)^2=0$, where $k^3+k-8=0$,
and we can get an exact roots, but it's very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$x^4+8x-1=\left(x^2-\sqrt a x +\frac a2+\frac4{\sqrt a}\right)\left(x^2+\sqrt a x +\frac a2-\frac4{\sqrt a}\right)=0
$$
where $a^3+4a-64=0$, yielding $a =\frac4{\sqrt3}\sinh\left( \frac13\sinh^{-1}(12\sqrt3)\right)$. Solve to obtain

$$x= -\frac{\sqrt a}2\pm\sqrt{\frac4{\sqrt a}- \frac a4 },\>\>\>
\frac{\sqrt a}2\pm i \sqrt{\frac4{\sqrt a}+\frac a4 }
$$

Answer (score 0):

All equations of degree $\le 4$ can be solved by general formulae. The ones for $4$-th degree equations may be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots). Unfortunately, they are so long that, even in your easy case when the coefficients of $x^3$ and $x^2$ are zero, they are too long to present here. Anyway, computer algebra systems can solve this explicitly, instantly; Mathematica outputs:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(3 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}}}}-\frac{1}{2}
\surd \left(-\frac{2 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}+\frac{2}{\left(3 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}-8 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(3
\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}}}\right), \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(3
\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}}}}+\frac{1}{2} \surd \left(-\frac{2 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}+\frac{2}{\left(3 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}-8
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(3 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}}}\right), \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(3 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}}}}-\frac{1}{2}
\surd \left(-\frac{2 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}+\frac{2}{\left(3 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}+8 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(3
\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}}}\right), \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(3
\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}}}}+\frac{1}{2} \surd \left(-\frac{2 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}+\frac{2}{\left(3 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}+8
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\frac{\left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)^{1/3}}{3^{2/3}}-\frac{1}{\left(3 \left(36+\sqrt{1299}\right)\right)^{1/3}}}}\right)$$

Answer (score -1):

hint see this article from wolramalpha its irreducible over $Q$ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20x%5E4%2B8%20x-1%20irreducible%3F&lk=2 if you want to find roots they are hard to find . $x\approx -2,0.12,0.95-\pm\sqrt{3}i$

Answer (score -1):

The two real roots $r_1, r_2$ are obtainable as follows.
Let
$$ \eqalign{
a_1 &= 2 \sqrt{1299} + 72\cr
a_2 &= 2 \cdot 18^{1/3} a_1^{2/3} - 12\cr
a_3 &= \sqrt{144 \sqrt{a_1} + 6 \sqrt{a_2} - 18^{1/3} a_1^{2/3} \sqrt{a_2}}\cr
r_1 &= \dfrac{18^{1/6}(2 a_3 - \sqrt{2} a_2^{3/4})}{12 a_1^{1/6} a_2^{1/4}}
\cr
r_2&= \dfrac{18^{1/6}(-2 a_3 - \sqrt{2} a_2^{3/4})}{12 a_1^{1/6} a_2^{1/4}}
}$$

I think that way of presenting them, taking advantage of common-subexpression elimination, is much less formidable-looking than writing them out in full.